# BeautifulSoup. How replace_with() changes tags for others

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I feel ashamed to ask this. I'm struggling with replace_with(). Just want to get how to change tags.

Here an example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "http://example.com/blabla/blublu/tata"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")  
page = page_soup.select_one(".list")
print(page)
if page:
    url = page.get("href")  
    newUrl = "http://example.com{}".format(url)
    Client = uReq(newUrl)
    pageHtml = Client.read()
    Client.close()      
    pSoup = soup(pageHtml, "html.parser")
    spot = pSoup.select(".view_details > h3")
    spots = spot[0].text
    print(spots)
    contain = pSoup.select(".info > table")

    #HERE I AM TRYING TO MAKE THE MAGIC

    for table in contain:
        table.find_all("table")
        table.replace_with("div")
    contains = contain[0]
    print(contains)
```

After changing some dummy mistakes. I just get the original text withouth changing the tags:

```
<table>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <div>Lorem ipsum...</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If someone can give me some light in this dark moments would be apreciated.

Comment: It should be `.findAll` instead of `find_all`, I guess

Comment: `select` returns a *list of elements*, so your `contain` is `list`. Probably you mean `for table in contain: table.find_all("table")`?

Comment: Yes. .findAll() mistake after many times. In reference to the code that you wrote: Do you mean like this? `for table in contain: 
         table.find_all("table")
  table.replace_with("div")
         contains = contain[0]
         print(contains)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say thanks for answering. What I get with this new code is the html complete but without changing table for div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a basis to go off from because it changes the tag name `table` to `div`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<table>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
            <div>Lorem ipsum...</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>''', 'html.parser')

tag = soup.table

tag.name = 'div'

print(tag)
```

Output:

```
<div>
 <tr valign="top">
  <td>
   <div>
    Lorem ipsum...
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe OP want to apply it in `for loop` :D

Comment: Maybe ‍♂️. Who knows if he ever came back.

Comment: Hi! I'm back! Sorry for the delay thought was getting notifications to the phone but was not like that. Yes have tried your answer and it works. Now I've to find the way to catch an specific table by class. Thanks a lot for your time!